# Rust, How to configure a workspace of libraries?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a workspace lets call `my_workspace`. `my_workspace` has a series of small libraries related but each one with their own responsibility. Something like:

```ini
[workspace]
members = [
    "my_lib_1",
    "my_lib_2",
    "my_lib_3",
    ...
]
```

And `my_workspace` are structured like this:

```
|my_lib_1/
|my_lib_2/
|my_lib_2/
|Cargo.toml
...
```

This workspace doesn't export any binaries only libraries.

The thing how I can configure my `Cargo.toml` to treat each members as a feature? to use like this:

```ini
# package that use the lib

[dependencies]
my_workspace = { ... , features = ["my_lib_1"] }
```

```rs
// inside of the package that use `my_workspace`
use my_workspace::my_lib_1;

fn do_something() {
    my_lib_1::whatever_that_exposes_this_lib();
}
```

I'm sorry if this is a noob question, but I can't find any information in the cargo documentation that would shed light on how to accomplish this.

Comment: I believe, in each library, you should create it's own crate `Cargo.toml`.
Then the main Cargo.toml can have a path in dependencies`my_workspace = { path = "path/to/my_workspace", features = ["my_lib_1"] }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like rust doesn't let me have a workspace as 'main' project, so instead I solved by adding a new crate that import all workspace members and reexport them with the `features` key in the `Cargo.toml` and the `#[cfg(feature)]` annotation in the `lib.rs` for each member.

Comment: Yes, this is the way. This is what e.g. [`gloo`](https://docs.rs/gloo) does.

Comment: I was doing something similar but I really liked the way gloo organizes its libraries and I ended up copying its structure